# Is circular scrolling possible in vim?

Tags: vim, scroll

Is it possible to configure vim such that a movement command "wraps around" the vertical (or horizontal) buffer?

In other words, assume I'm on line 2 in a buffer, in visual mode.  I press `3k`.  My cursor is now positioned on the last line of the buffer.

Or more simply, my cursor is on the first line of the file -- I press `k`.  Now my cursor flips to the last line of the file.

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find any references searching for "circular scrolling" or "wrap-around scrolling".

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of the terms ("circular" or "wrap-around ..."; do they come from the emacs side of the family?), so you might perhaps clarify a bit better about what kind of scrolling you're interested in, and then somebody might be able to help. Vim has various means of movement. So far I haven't found any I couldn't (at least) emulate, if it was not natively available.

Comment: @Idigas if you know vim then my explanation of movement commands should be crystal clear, speculative terminology aside.

Comment: Might be a question for [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @g33kz0r - No need for that tone, I'm trying to help. Let's assume that I've Vim once or twice in my life. If you have a buffer with let's say 20 lines, and you're on line 2, enter visual mode, press 3k, you'll end up on the first line ... according to my understanding.

Comment: @Idigas.  That's a correct description of vim's default functionality.  My question is whether it's possible to somehow override or modify that behavior, so that the cursor "flips" to the bottom of the buffer by *n-x* lines, where *n* is the number in front of the movement command,  and *x* is the number of lines between the cursor and the top of the screen.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably possible with some vimscript hackery, but it's much more universal to become efficient with motions like `G` to go to the bottom of a file and `gg` or `1G` or `<C-Home>` to go to the top of the file. Likewise, `$` for the end of a line and `0` for the beginning of the line or `^` for the first non-blank character.

You can also set `:help whichwrap`, which specifies which keys will move of to the next line when moving past the end of the line or move to the previous line when moving past the beginning of the line. Other then that I don't think there's built in functionality for what you're asking. You can could do it with some vimscript but it would require remapping h,j,k, and l to functions and handling whether they are at the end/beginning of the line/file. To me that seems overkill and rather messy.

All that being said, if you must...

```
nnoremap j :call CheckJ()<cr>
nnoremap k :call CheckK()<cr>
nnoremap h :call CheckH()<cr>
nnoremap l :call CheckL()<cr>

fun! CheckJ()
   if line('.') == line('$')
      norm! gg
   else
      norm! j
   endif
endfun

fun! CheckK()
   if line('.') == 1
      norm! G
   else
      norm! k
   endif
endfun

fun! CheckH()
   if col('.') == 1
      norm! $
   else
      norm! h
   endif
endfun

fun! CheckL()
   if col('.') == (col('$') - 1)
      norm! 0
   else
      norm! l
   endif
endfun
```

Comment: How would one do this in vimscript?

Comment: @g33kz0r the example I provided doesn't account for [count]j etc. You can use `v:count` to get the count. It would be more complicated but possible to account for `v:count` if you did for example, `5k` on line 3.

Answer (score 4):

Vim is a *text* editor, and text has both physical and logical properties of having a beginning and an end, both in columns and lines. Therefore, the feature you're requesting doesn't exist, and probably won't ever be included in Vim.

It can, however, with some effort be emulated in Vimscript, by binding most movement commands to custom implementations. But that would introduce inconsistencies in the usage model, as ranges (e.g. `:42,10`) still wouldn't wrap around.

Why would you want such a wrap-around? Is this for a particular file type, or are you used to it from another editor?

Comment: +1 this is a better answer.  Seems like you're saying this would be inconsistent with vim's design, which I will buy.  I'm used to vim -- it's all I use.  The genesis of this idea is that when programming with `set relativenumber`, the line numbers appear to do exactly what I've described; that is, they "wrap around" the buffer vertically.  It would be nice if the cursor could also do this.