# Loop back to first line after last in vim

Tags: vim, editor, settings

I would like to know if there is a setting that will move the cursor back to the first line if I try to move beyond the last line while editing a document. Ideally, it should work in both Normal and Insert modes.

Similar to what `whichwrap` lets me do horizontally, but *vertically*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380689/is-circular-scrolling-possible-in-vim

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it.